# Laravel output different that system time?

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am using laravel with forge. I have papertrail set and and different commands that should be triggered at specific time. i.e. 4am.

I noticed today that it still didnt run the command so I did some digging. Now my system time is:

```
     Local time: Fri 2017-09-15 09:00:55 BST
  Universal time: Fri 2017-09-15 08:00:55 UTC
        RTC time: Fri 2017-09-15 08:00:55
       Time zone: Europe/London (BST, +0100)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: yes
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Which is correct. However, my papertrail is telling me from the logs:

Sep 15 01:00:55 CRON: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user forge

So it seems like laravel/php is behind. Timezone in app.php is set to 'timezone' => 'Europe/London'

What else could be wrong?

Comment: Just a guess as I no longer develop on Laravel. Are the commands run by php cli? If so, then specifying the correct timezone in php.ini could help.

Comment: Either that, or the application (Laravel) is using a different timezone. check your timezone in config/app.php

Comment: I've set both in php.ini and laravel config to Europe/London and still the same

Comment: Have you checked that you don't have a separate php.ini for php cli? And did you restart php process and/or webserver?

Comment: I checked php --ini and found which one it is using. And yes I did

Comment: If I do echo "The time is " . date("h:i:sa"); Time seems to be correct

Comment: Any chance you are going to react on the solutions?

Answer (score 0):

maybe it works for you:

in app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php there a boot function. add following to that:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Your/TimeZone');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the correct timezone in the `config/app.php` file. I think that the Laravel sets the time for you.